# Why $Aut_R(M)$ (Autmorphism as $R$module) is $M^{\times}$(unit group of a ring)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ and $M$ be a commutative ring.
Suppose $M$ be $R$ module.

Then, is it true that $Aut_R(M)$ (Autmorphism as $R$module) is $M^{\times}$(unit group of a ring) ?

Comment: Try on simple examples, e.g. $\mathbb C$ as a $\mathbb R$-module (i.e. vector space of dimension $2$).

Comment: There's no reason $\text{Aut}_R(M)$ should be abelian, and in examples it usually won't be, e.g. take $R$ a field.